# Java Generics query

Tags: java, generics

I see following method definition in Spring Batch StepBuilder class. What is the use of first angle bracket here?

```
public <I, O> SimpleStepBuilder<I, O> chunk(int chunkSize) {
    return (new SimpleStepBuilder(this)).chunk(chunkSize);
}
```

Comment: It defines generic types `I` and `O` that are local to that method.

Comment: It defines `I` and `O` types which in you case are subsequently used for your return type `SimpleStepBuilder<I, O>`. 
This means that when you invoke your chunk method say by following: `yourObject.<Cat, Dog>.chunk(0)`, you will receive `SimpleStepBuilder` instance parametrized by `Cat` and `Dog` types, i.e `SimpleStepBuilder<Cat, Dog>`

Comment: Just to mention: `O` is not a great name for a (type) variable. It looks a lot like `0` in certain fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `<I, O>` is the *definition* of the types. You are defining a list of generic "placeholder" names (and, optionally, their constraints) which may then be used within the method or signature in place of a "real" type.

The second `<I, O>` is parameterising `SimpleStepBuilder`. Just as you may parameterise `ArrayList` as `ArrayList<String>`, here you are parameterising `SimpleStepBuilder` with two generic types: `I` and `O`.

---

It may be helpful to look at a different method which returns a String and, instead, uses the generic type parameters to define the method's parameters:

```
public <I, O> String chunk(I input, O output) {
    return input.toString() + output.toString();
}
```